# Layout gets shifted upwards on adding scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am trying to make my activity scrollable so I enclosed the Relative layout inside a scrollview. But what it does is that it shifts the entire layout upwards. Can someone help in solving the issue?

This is the xml file for the activity;

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="nmss.example.com.coach.UserProfile">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_statusd"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tv_statusd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/et_age"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Status"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="80"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_age"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/et_height"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_statusd"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Age"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_height"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/et_weight"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_age"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Height"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_weight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/et_exp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Weight"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_exp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/et_bio"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_weight"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Experiences"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_bio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_done"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_exp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Bio"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:text="Done" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="PROFILE"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the layout preview before adding scrollview

[image]

This is the layout preview after adding scrollview

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this properties to `Scroll View`. Modify your `Scroll View` as below. No need to replace any other `layout`.

This properties `android:fillViewport="true"` and `android:scrollbars="vertical"` will do that.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

*`This displays the elements properly. But when I click on an edit text, the whole layout shifts upwards and everything gets haphazard. What to do for that?`*

Add this line to your `Activity` and try. `Adjust Resize` and `Adjust Pan` will do that.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Try to define that inside `manifest activity`.

```
<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

Use this edited `XML`. Made some modification.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="nmss.example.com.coach.UserProfile">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="PROFILE"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_statusd"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tv_statusd"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Status"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="80"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_statusd"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_statusd"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Age"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_height"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_age"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_age"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Height"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_weight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Weight"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_exp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_weight"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_weight"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Experiences"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="3"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_bio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_exp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_exp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Bio"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="3"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_bio"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Done" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace RelativeLayout to LinearLayout it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

Or use this

```
android:fillViewport="true"   
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

inside Scrollview.